# Unable to install coursera-dl

Tags: python, cmd, coursera-api

I accidentally deleted a file I think called coursera-dl.exe from C:\python310\lib\site-packages. I tried to uninstall it using:

```
pip uninstall coursera-dl
```

it showed this warning:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -oursera-dl (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -oursera-dl (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
```

but it was successfully uninstalled.

I tried to reinstall it using:

```
pip install coursera-dl
```

but it gives this error:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -oursera-dl (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -oursera-dl (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
Requirement already satisfied: coursera-dl in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (0.11.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5.0 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from coursera-dl) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: keyring>=4.0 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from coursera-dl) (23.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.10.0 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from coursera-dl) (2.28.1)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4>=4.1.3 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from coursera-dl) (4.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: configargparse>=0.12.0 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from coursera-dl) (1.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.7 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from coursera-dl) (0.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs==18.1.0 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from coursera-dl) (18.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3>=1.23 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from coursera-dl) (1.26.12)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from beautifulsoup4>=4.1.3->coursera-dl) (2.3.2.post1)
Requirement already satisfied: jaraco.classes in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from keyring>=4.0->coursera-dl) (3.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes!=0.1.0,!=0.1.1 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from keyring>=4.0->coursera-dl) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.10.0->coursera-dl) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3,>=2 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.10.0->coursera-dl) (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.10.0->coursera-dl) (2022.6.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: more-itertools in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from jaraco.classes->keyring>=4.0->coursera-dl) (8.14.0)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -oursera-dl (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -oursera-dl (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall coursera-dl
```

or

```
pip install --ignore-installed coursera-dl
```

Comment: It finally worked, thanks. But there's one more issue, it gives a 404 error when I try to download a course. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Could you raise a new question fr this new issue? (and include the details)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74662735/cannot-download-using-coursera-dl-error-404