# Cannot download using coursera-dl, Error 404

Tags: python, cmd, coursera-api

I am trying to use coursera-dl in windows to download coursera videos using this command:

```
coursera-dl neural-networks-deep-learning
```

it gives this error:

```
coursera_dl version 0.11.5
Downloading class: neural-networks-deep-learning (1 / 1)
Parsing syllabus of on-demand course (id=W_mOXCrdEeeNPQ68_4aPpA). This may take some time, please be patient ...
Error 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://api.coursera.org/api/onDemandCourseMaterials.v1/?q=slug&slug=neural-networks-deep-learning&includes=moduleIds%2ClessonIds%2CpassableItemGroups%2CpassableItemGroupChoices%2CpassableLessonElements%2CitemIds%2Ctracks&fields=moduleIds%2ConDemandCourseMaterialModules.v1(name%2Cslug%2Cdescription%2CtimeCommitment%2ClessonIds%2Coptional)%2ConDemandCourseMaterialLessons.v1(name%2Cslug%2CtimeCommitment%2CelementIds%2Coptional%2CtrackId)%2ConDemandCourseMaterialPassableItemGroups.v1(requiredPassedCount%2CpassableItemGroupChoiceIds%2CtrackId)%2ConDemandCourseMaterialPassableItemGroupChoices.v1(name%2Cdescription%2CitemIds)%2ConDemandCourseMaterialPassableLessonElements.v1(gradingWeight)%2ConDemandCourseMaterialItems.v1(name%2Cslug%2CtimeCommitment%2Ccontent%2CisLocked%2ClockableByItem%2CitemLockedReasonCode%2CtrackId)%2ConDemandCourseMaterialTracks.v1(passablesCount)&showLockedItems=true getting page https://api.coursera.org/api/onDemandCourseMaterials.v1/?q=slug&slug=neural-networks-deep-learning&includes=moduleIds%2ClessonIds%2CpassableItemGroups%2CpassableItemGroupChoices%2CpassableLessonElements%2CitemIds%2Ctracks&fields=moduleIds%2ConDemandCourseMaterialModules.v1(name%2Cslug%2Cdescription%2CtimeCommitment%2ClessonIds%2Coptional)%2ConDemandCourseMaterialLessons.v1(name%2Cslug%2CtimeCommitment%2CelementIds%2Coptional%2CtrackId)%2ConDemandCourseMaterialPassableItemGroups.v1(requiredPassedCount%2CpassableItemGroupChoiceIds%2CtrackId)%2ConDemandCourseMaterialPassableItemGroupChoices.v1(name%2Cdescription%2CitemIds)%2ConDemandCourseMaterialPassableLessonElements.v1(gradingWeight)%2ConDemandCourseMaterialItems.v1(name%2Cslug%2CtimeCommitment%2Ccontent%2CisLocked%2ClockableByItem%2CitemLockedReasonCode%2CtrackId)%2ConDemandCourseMaterialTracks.v1(passablesCount)&showLockedItems=true
The server replied: <html>
        <head>
                <title>Coursera - API Route Does Not Exist</title>
        </head>
        <body style="background-color:#e4e4e4">
                <div style="position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; margin:auto; height:200px; width: 600px">
                        <div style="text-align:center">
                                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/coursera/error_pages/coursera-logo.svg" width="400">
                        </div>
                        <h1 style="text-align:center; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:100; color: #555">
                                API Route Does Not Exist
                        </h1>
                        <div style="text-align:center; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:300; font-size:13pt; color: #555">
                                Edge does not know about this API route. <br>
                                Check whether this route is exposed in the routing table.
                        </div>
                </div>
        </body>
</html>
HTTPError 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://api.coursera.org/api/onDemandCourseMaterials.v1/?q=slug&slug=neural-networks-deep-learning&includes=moduleIds%2ClessonIds%2CpassableItemGroups%2CpassableItemGroupChoices%2CpassableLessonElements%2CitemIds%2Ctracks&fields=moduleIds%2ConDemandCourseMaterialModules.v1(name%2Cslug%2Cdescription%2CtimeCommitment%2ClessonIds%2Coptional)%2ConDemandCourseMaterialLessons.v1(name%2Cslug%2CtimeCommitment%2CelementIds%2Coptional%2CtrackId)%2ConDemandCourseMaterialPassableItemGroups.v1(requiredPassedCount%2CpassableItemGroupChoiceIds%2CtrackId)%2ConDemandCourseMaterialPassableItemGroupChoices.v1(name%2Cdescription%2CitemIds)%2ConDemandCourseMaterialPassableLessonElements.v1(gradingWeight)%2ConDemandCourseMaterialItems.v1(name%2Cslug%2CtimeCommitment%2Ccontent%2CisLocked%2ClockableByItem%2CitemLockedReasonCode%2CtrackId)%2ConDemandCourseMaterialTracks.v1(passablesCount)&showLockedItems=true
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 5):

The error you shared seems to be related to an open issue on the tool's GitHub repository ([Issue #834](https://github.com/coursera-dl/coursera-dl/issues/834), still open on Dec. 11, 2022). Until addressed, you can try a fix made on a fork, for example, [this one](https://github.com/coursera-dl/coursera-dl/issues/834#issuecomment-1314392270).

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://github.com/coursera-dl/coursera-dl#running-the-script) you should download as follows:

```
coursera-dl -u my_coursera_username -p my_coursera_password neural-networks-deep-learning
```

Note that you won't be able to access the course materials if you are not officially enrolled via the website.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I put my username, password etc.. in a `.conf` file. I tried this before and it worked. I read somewhere that coursera-dl is not working anymore and you need to download the repository then install it but this solution doesn't work and it gives the same warning mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74631073/unable-to-install-coursera-dl/74658751#74658751) when typing `pip3 install` or `pip install coursera-dl`. [The mentioned solution](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=fDCln4C0zbI)

Comment: "You must already have (manually) agreed to the Honor of Code of the particular courses that you want to use with coursera-dl". Did you perform these steps?

Comment: I did, still not working.